# How to get the path of the Databricks Notebook dynamically?

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

Please don't give solution for IPython/Jupyter notebooks. The technology is different.

I want to get the path of my Databricks notebook dynamically. Which is something I can get from the UI "Copy File Path" as shown below. I am not able to use `__file__` as that is giving me error.

```
NameError: name '__file__' is not defined
```

[image]

Comment: @Evgeny no it isn't. My question is for Databricks.

Comment: This question is about databricks, a completely different platform from the referenced "duplicate".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each notebook has so-called "context" that contains a lot of information about environment, including the HTTP Path, hostname, etc.  It could be retrieved as Python dict with something like this (it's simpler to convert to JSON & back than to fetch fields by `.get` functions):

```py
import json
ctx = json.loads(dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().toJson())
```

inside the `ctx` dictionary there is a subdictionary named `extraContext`, that contains field `notebook_path` that is what you need:

```py
nb_path = ctx['extraContext']['notebook_path']
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is anything like that available for you, it can be found by inspecting `globals()` and `locals()`, e.g.

```py
print(globals())
```

In my case, the closest to this I found was:

```py
_dh
```

e.g.:

```py
print(_dh)
# ['/media/win10/Users/norok2/Downloads']
```

Comment: For Databricks it is giving `['/databricks/driver']` , which is not my expected output.

Comment: Have you asked DataBricks customer care? It may be your best shot.

Comment: I am using community version of DBR. I don't think they will help.

Comment: Hi @AnirbanNag'tintinmj' you can retrieve the notebook paths using their REST API: https://docs.databricks.com/api/latest/workspace.html#list

However, you have mentioned that you are using the community version. So please confirm first by trying API call if you have access to the REST API or not.

Comment: I want to get the notebook path where I am writing the code. So I can use that for logging purpose.

Comment: This can be done in Scala: dbutils.notebook.getContext.notebookPath. If needed for Python or R, you will need to retrieve the path using %Scala cmd then pass the value to a widget where it can be retrieved using Python or R.